# Sci-fi novel series with instant travel between planets through gates. A river runs through the gates

Tags: story-identification, novel

The main technology was a sort of gate that enabled instant travel from planet to planet through a gate on the surface. I think there was a river that ran on several different planets, through these gates.

One scene had the inventor waving at astronauts who thought they were the first humans on Mars.

Answer (score 37):

I think you’ve conflated two different series, both of which have fixed interstellar teleport portals. The river that runs between different planets through the teleport portals is from the *[Hyperion Cantos](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperion_Cantos)* series by Dan Simmons — it’s called the [River Tethys](https://hyperioncantos.fandom.com/wiki/River_Tethys). But the inventor of the portals waving at the first astronauts on Mars is the opening scene of the *[Commonwealth Saga](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga)* by Peter F Hamilton.

Comment: I think you are right. I have read both series and the similar tech probably merged in memory.  I really appreciate this answer.

Comment: Though the Commonwealth saga DOES have the "Silfen Paths" which wind through other worlds without using the traditional portals, and I may be misremembering myself but I believe at least part of Ozzie's journey through them was on a river?  That could also have led to some confusion between the concepts.

Comment: There's a part in the commonwealth saga where two characters are backpacking and following aliens through some different connected areas.  The OP might be thinking of that part.

Comment: @LockeWiggin Please accept this answer as correct, if you believe it is right.